# Problem with page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

**The qustion was modified by me to show a complete picture.**

I have a basic question:

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int firstPageIndex = 0;
     int lastPageIndex = 5;


    if (TotalPageNumber > 5)
    {
          if ((TotalPageNumber - PageIndex) <= 5)
            firstPageIndex = TotalPageNumber - 5;

        firstPageIndex = PageIndex < 3 ? 0 : PageIndex - 2;
    }
    else
    {
        firstPageIndex = 0;
        lastPageIndex = TotalPageNumber;
    }


    for (int i = firstPageIndex; i < firstPageIndex + lastPageIndex; i++)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
        lnk.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
        lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lblPageNumber_Click);
        lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
        lnk.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        plcPagerHolder.Controls.Add(lnk);
    }    }

  int _pageIndex;
  public int PageIndex
  {
      get
      {
          object objPage = ViewState["_pageIndex"];

          if (objPage == null)
          {
              _pageIndex = 0;
          }
          else
          {
              _pageIndex = (int)objPage;
          }

          return _pageIndex;
      }
      set {ViewState["_pageIndex"] = value; }
  }



   protected void lnkPagerNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageIndex = PageIndex == TotalPageNumber - 1 ? 0 : PageIndex + 1;
  }
```

The problem is with Page_Load event, I expect to get new PageIndex after the linkbutton is clicked.

**Update:**
My Foo adds new controls to the page, based on provide Page index so I guess I can't put it in Prerender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         Foo (PageIndex);    
     }
  }

  protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {                
      PageIndex = int.Parse(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
      Foo (PageIndex);  
  }
```

or

```
  protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {                
      Foo (PageIndex);  
  }
```

Comment: You could also use Page_LoadComplete instead of PreRender

Comment: @toraan: you still have the option 1 or using Page_LoadComplete as others suggest

Comment: My page is a user control and Page_LoadComplete is not triggered there

Comment: @Claudio Redi,no because the controls that I add to page are those links that i click, (I should explained it better, in page load I create them and assign click event).

Comment: No it's not, when I click on the linkbutton ther is a postback so, page is re-rendered without the linkbuttons! so the click even't can't be fired!!!

Answer (score 2):

you can place Foo (PageIndex) in Page_LoadComplete event instead of Page_Load, i.e.

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Foo (PageIndex);     
}
```

LoadComplete event is raised after Control events.

Edit: 
LoadComplete is the earliest place where you can safely access new pageindex and also you can add there another controls, but that is possible also in PreRender.

Answer (score 0):

And you will, but Page_Load gets called before the event handler for the linkbutton .. so, you can't really expect it to be changed yet.